# How to add reusable custom views programmatically? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xib, nscoding

I've created a reusable xib file that contains a table and it's being loaded in a `TableView.swift` file like this:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)    
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TableView", owner: self, options: nil)
}
```

*I'm only mentioning this to clarify that I am not confused about how to load the xib file*

---

I can easily load the reusable view in my `RootViewController.swift` file by adding a view to the `UIViewController` and giving that view a custom class like this:

[image]

and then creating an outlet for that view like this:

[image]

**So here is my question:**

Why am I not able to simply add the view like this:

```
let tableViewView = TableView()
```

When I do, I get an error that I don't totally understand:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override the frame initializer as well.

Assuming your `TableView` class is a `UITableView` subclass, it should look something like this:

```
class TableView: UITableView {

    override init(frame: CGRect, style: UITableViewStyle) {
        super.init(frame: frame, style: style)
        // any additional setup code
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        // any additional setup code
    }

}
```

Because you are trying to instantiate the table view programmatically, you need to give it an initializer for the frame, not only an initializer with a coder.